# why strapi using cloudinary as a cloud storage does not return images link onteh api calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, strapi

I make strapi+cloudinary integration works, but when i try to call the strapi api (/api/posts) the image attributes doesn't come inside the json file, for some reason media starpi attributes is hidden from requests(or there is some error there).

//api/posts

```
{"data":
[{
"id":1,
"attributes":
{
"title":"li fogo na bran bran ya",
"slug":"li-fogo-na-bran-bran-ya",
"conteudo":"\n\nWhat is Lorem Ipsum?\nLorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the ...(injected humour and the like).\n\n",
"lingua":"en",
"imageName":"coyas",
"createdAt":"2022-03-19T11:16:27.549Z",
"updatedAt":"2022-03-19T11:16:35.170Z",
"publishedAt":"2022-03-19T11:16:35.166Z"}}],
"meta":{"pagination":
{
"page":1,
"pageSize":25,
"pageCount":1,
"total":1
}}}

// so where is the imagem field
```

[image]

the integratin with strapi is working fine

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  upload: {
    config: {
      provider: "cloudinary",
      providerOptions: {
        cloud_name: env("CLOUDINARY_NAME"),
        api_key: env("CLOUDINARY_KEY"),
        api_secret: env("CLOUDINARY_SECRET"),
      },
      actionOptions: {
        upload: {},
        delete: {},
      },
    },
  },
```

I'm using the @strapi/provider-upload-cloudinary for storage upload

what i need to do to get those hiddens attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried altering your api endpoint to "/api/posts?populate=*" ? I believe you have to explicitly tell Strapi to populate relations, etc in order to get them returned via the api call.

Comment: how to alter that please?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by “alter”. You have to request that Strapi populate relations by adding the ‘populate” request parameter as stated above. See the Strapi docs for more info.